# Cannot access empty property - Joomla! JDatabaseMysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I was receiving the following fatal error, running Joomla 2.5, but only while trying to access the administrative view of a custom component I have created (which accessed the database):

Fatal Error: Cannot access empty property in \libraries\joomla\database\database\mysqli.php on line 498"

The context of line 498 is:

```
protected function fetchObject($cursor = null, $class = 'stdClass'
{
return mysqli_fetch_object($cursor ? $cursor : $this->cursor, $class);
}
```

Bizarrely, even after removing the `$this->cursor` statement like so:

```
protected function fetchObject($cursor = null, $class = 'stdClass'
{
return mysqli_fetch_object($cursor, $class);
}
```

**I received the same error,** despite the fact that that line no longer contains a member access operator.

How could I be receiving this error even though no properties are being accessed in that line?

Comment: Are you sure you made the change in the right file, and uploading it (or whatever) worked out?

Comment: I traced the problem to the mysqli_fetch_object function thanks to the comments on this page of the official php documentation at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

The query I was using contained empty strings (and, therefore, empty column names) in the select statement (i.e. SELECT "", something, "", something.else...) This resulted in empty column names, which mysqli_fetch_object cannot tolerate.